# Game programming in C# - Where to start?

Tags: c#

I work as a system developer, mainly programming information systems in C# for web, desktop and server environments. Now I'd like to have a go at game development in C# just for the sake of the challenge and expanding my horizons, but where do I start? I've had a look at XNA, but I heard that it's on the way out.

Where does one begin?

Comment: This probably isn't a good format question for StackOverflow but I'd like to hear the suggestions.

Comment: If you want to learn, I suggest leveraging an existing framework/engine that does lots of the low-level heavy lifting for you. That way you can focus on effective game _design_ and getting your feet wet with other aspects (3D modelling, event scripting, audio, GUI, physics). Check out [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/) and focus on their C# API (they support other languages, but stick with C# since you have experience with it)

Comment: I don't think we'll hear about any replacement for XNA until we get nearer the release of the XBox One. MS have [hinted at a replacement for XNA](http://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-hints-at-replacement-for-xna-for-xbox-one-indie-game-creators), but it remains unclear whether this will be just for XBox One, or if it will also support Windows or Windows RT. In the meanwhile, XNA lives on in the form of [`MonoGame`](http://monogame.codeplex.com/), an open-source implementation of XNA 4. I think its free for windows, and maybe also for the versions for iOS and Android.

Answer (score 2):

I know this says "Teens" but it may be worth a look: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Visual-Programming-Teens-Course-Technology/dp/1435458486/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1371394387&sr=8-3&keywords=c%23+game

I just saw this today funnily enough, I have no affiliate with the author (or Amazon)

Comment: This does indeed look interesting! I wonder if it's available in an E-book format..

Comment: If its on Amazon, I would think so?

Comment: Yes, I found it! Was just thinking loudly, hehe :) Thanks again for the book suggestion!